# Comandos abaixo do setAdapter sendo executados antes do getView()

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

Estou criando alguns adapters no meu aplicativo e me surgiu essa dúvida em um problema que estou tendo.

Eu tenho um código do tipo:

```
public class ActivityCompra extends AppCompatActivity {

    Adapter a;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_compra);

        //...

        Thread busca = new Thread();
        busca.execute();
        fazOperacao3();

    }

private class Thread extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            //...
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            //...
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean ok){
            if(ok){
                a = new Adapter();
                lista.setAdapter(a);
                cancel(true);
                fazOperacao1();
                fazOperacao2();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

As funcões `fazOperacao1()`, `fazOperacao2()`  e `fazOperacao3()`são executadas antes da view da `ListView` ser montada, e só depois o getView é chamado para setar os componentes de layout.

Eu preciso executar essas operações depois que a view já estiver toda montada e não estou sabendo como fazer isso.

Acho que é uma coisa bem simples mas estou tendo muita dificuldade.

Answer (score 1):

É estranho a fazOperacao1 e fazOperacao2 serem executadas antes da listView ser montada, porque estão na linha de baixo, e nessa área o código é executado linha por linha.
Mas, de qualquer forma, é só usar um callback para resolver seus problemas.

```
public interface MinhaResposta{
    void onResponse(boolean resposta);
}



private class Thread extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        private MinhaResposta resposta;

        public Thread(MinhaResposta resposta){
             this.resposta = resposta;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            //...
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            //...
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean ok){
            resposta.onResponse(ok);
        }
    }
}



public class ActivityCompra extends AppCompatActivity {

    Adapter a;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_compra);

        //...

        Thread busca = new Thread(new MinhaResposta(){
              // toda a lógica do onPostExecute
              fazOperacao3(); // aqui vc tem certeza que esse método só será executado após a asynctask ser finalizada
        });
        busca.execute();

    }
```

Comment: Olá! Desculpa a demora pra dar um retorno.Não entendi muito bem o que está acontecendo no seu código, poderia me explicar? Eu preciso executar a AsynkTask antes de fazer as ações do onPostExecute, pois faço consultas no banco de dados e esses dados são utilizados no método

Comment: a asynctask só executa o onpostexecute após ter certeza que o doinbackground foi finalizado, mesmo se for operações de rede.